Flutter with Riverpod - jumping from Angular and Spring Boot
I am jumping from Angular and Spring Boot, and Flutter seems pretty new and different for me. I started creating project with Riverpod for state management and have some questions about architecture and good practices.

Where should I keep my business logic? Normally in Angular or in Spring Boot I created services classes and injected them when needed. Here I don't get the DI so much. Should I create a Riverpod provider for a Service and in such way inject my service? Or should I rather not use services at all and keep the logic in Notifier providers?
The "new" syntax in Riverpod seems to be pretty hard to understand, specially with those annotations, is there a better way to manage state?



If the service has an observable state that should be able to be modified by calling some methods, make it a notifier. If not, simply wrap it with a provider (even if it doesn't have an observable state, for the purpose of DI). 2) The new codegen syntax is intended to make defining providers/notifiers easier. You still have option to use the non-codegen syntax though. In the docs, you can turn off the "Code generation" option in the sidebar.


first of all in Flutter you can use many state managers, like riverpod, bloc or Get_It.
I suggest you to use Riverpod, because it is the simplest and cleanest package  (in my opinion).
Thus for me your choice (to start using Riverpod) is right.
Now, in Riverpod you should understand the concept of Provider.
A Provider is a function that creates a service. Like , very close to a Spring Bean.
In fact suppose you want to create MyService like that:
 @Bean    
 class MyService {
    @Autowired 
    private AnotherBean another;
    
    public String sayHallo(int guess) {
           return another.makeTheMessage(guess);
    }
 }

Using dart you should declare:
class MyService {
    final AnotherBean another;
    MyService(this.another);
    String sayHallo(int guess) => another.makeTheMessage(guess);
}

More or less that's why the say that dart was born from a marriage between java and javascript (google says it).
Now, the problem is:

How to handle the @Bean annotation in Riverpod/Dart
How to inject a-la-SpringBean the Another bean to our service.

Now I show you how:
in a new file, I suggest you to call it providers.dart you should declare all providers. This file is not needed in java because of the annotation resolution process is quite handly (and better) in java than in Dart (but it seems that in future this thing should change):
@riverpod
AnotherBean anotherBean(AnotherBeanRef ref ) {
    return AnotherBean (  ) ;
}

@riverpod
MyService myService(MyServiceRef ref ) {
    return MyService ( ref.watch(anHotherServiceProvider) ) ;
}

As your can notice this file is the dependency injection resolution that is handled by Riverpod.
But, wait! in Spring all services are singleton, and in Riverpod ?
This is not true because the use a different way to handle their life cycle.
So you should change only the annotation declaration:
@riverpod

to:
@Riverpod(keeyAlive: true)

That's it! now you have your services managed a-la-spring.
You can have also async providers.
Now, let's talk about the view part.
I don't know Angular, I studied and worked on Facebook's ReactJS, and in fact Flutter is very close to ReactJS.
In fact when I studied Flutter for the first time  I suspected they had copied
ReactJS and ported it to Dart world.
obviously that's not true, but ReactJS and Flutter are very similar.
I think that starting from Angular you start a little far away,  but it will not be a problem for you: flutter has been made to be drastically simple.
in the View part you should declare a Riverpod that is quite "different" as the usual: it should notify the view page when the state has been changed.
The new riverpod notifier is called NotifierProvider.
Suppose you should show a number in a page, and update it (as the famous Flutter example page).
You should do like this:
@riverpod

class Counter extends _$Counter  {
  @override
  CounterModel build() {
    return CounterModel ( theValue: 0 ) ;
  }

  void increment() {
        state = CounterModel ( theValue:  state.value+1 );
  }
} 

This is a provider that notifies the Widget when its state has been changed
Note that in the increment() method, to notify the View , I had to change the CounterModel object itself: not to modify it! In fact in Flutter the Model objects should be always "freezed", unmodifiable. In fact it decides to notify the view only if the new state is another object from the old one .
Obviously here I used an odd "CounterModel" instead of a more correct  int type only to show you this concept.
Now let's see the view:
class CounterWidget extends ConsumerWidget {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

      final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
      return ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Value: ${counter.theValue}'),
        onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment(),
      );
    }
  }

Note that in the CounterWidget we have:

The registration of the provider : ref.watch(counterProvider) registers the notifier and update the view when it is needed.
In the call backs ( like a button press event ) we use the ref.read(...) instead , because we do not need to register again it, and we want only to use the increment method (they call it as side-effect of the notifier), it changes the state that will cause the view repaint event.

That's all!
So, we have the server-side implemented with @riverpod providers, and the view part implemented with the Provider Notifiers.
I suggest you to read first the riverpod documentation, then to read all other resources.
for simple View state management Riverpod's author suggest you to use not riverpod itself, but flutter_hooks, that is a simplified version of riverpod.
flutter_hooks is used for "ephemeral" states, viceversa for app states you should use riverpod.
For "ephemeral state" they intend states like: animations, simple view changes (color changes), text fields changes...little changes that must be managed inside a simple class. For a state that should be shared across all the app (App state), you should use riverpod.
in fact in this little example I showed you an ephemeral state, thus for a more correct use of a state manager, I should have used flutter_hooks and not riverpod, but I suggest you to use and keep "expert" of riverpod first , and use it in every state management, then you can increase a bit your skill using flutter_hooks.
I hope to have clarified your doubts.
Bye.
